# Problem making grid template columns and rows responsive

Tags: html, css

Morning,

I've been trying to improve my grid layouts, but I feel this isn't the most elegant way to create this layout, especially as I'm not sure how to make it responsive and prevent grid blowout.

Ideally, the text would shrink alongside the image (according to the font-size clamp settings) until a certain px breakpoint and then it would revert to flex-display:column, but I was wondering if there is a way to do it without a media query and just by setting better minmax properties for my columns and rows.

Is this an efficient way to get this result? And, how might I go about making to responsive to mobile?

Thank you

```
<div class="servicesOne">
    <img class="grid-item-four-one border-item-four-one" src=" <?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?> \assets\images\servicesImg.png" alt="Our Services" srcset="">

    <h2 class="grid-item-four-two">Why <span style="color:#7EC8E3">JD3D</span>?</h2>

    <p class="grid-item-four-three"> Hendis et, omnimo et eum renduciati que nonse vollaccus verfernatur, odicit quatempossi ut int reratiam verorum.
        Hendis et, omnimo et eum renduciati que nonse vollaccus verfernatur, odicit quatempossi ut int reratiam verorum.
        Hendis et, omnimo et eum renduciati que nonse vollaccus verfernatur.
    </p>
</div>
```

```
.servicesOne {
  padding-top: 2.25rem;
  gap: 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, minmax(50px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: minmax(100px, max-content) repeat(auto-fill, 90px) 20%;
  align-items: start;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.grid-item-four-one{
  border-color: #7ec8e3; 
  border-style: solid;
  margin-right: 2rem;
  padding: 1.2rem;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  grid-area: 3/2/7/6;
  display: block;
}

.grid-item-four-two {
  margin-top: -2rem;
  color: #0d0d0d;
  font-size: clamp(2.75rem, 5.5vw, 5rem);
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-bottom:1rem;
  align-self: end;
  grid-area: 3/6/4/9;
}

.grid-item-four-three {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  padding-left: 0.75rem;
  padding-top:1rem;
  align-self: end;
  grid-area: 4/6/7/8;
  font-size: clamp(.75rem, 2vw, 1.4rem)

}
```

```css
.servicesOne {
  padding-top: 2.25rem;
  gap: 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, minmax(50px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: minmax(100px, max-content) repeat(auto-fill, 90px) 20%;
  align-items: start;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.grid-item-four-one{
  margin-right: 2rem;
  padding: 1.2rem;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  grid-area: 3/2/7/6;
  display: block;
}



.grid-item-four-two {
  margin-top: -2rem;
  color: #0d0d0d;
  font-size: clamp(2.75rem, 5vw, 5rem);
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-bottom:1.5rem;
  align-self: end;
  grid-area: 3/6/4/9;
}

.grid-item-four-three {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  padding-left: 0.75rem;
  padding-top:1rem;
  align-self: end;
  grid-area: 4/6/7/8;
  font-size: clamp(.75rem, 2vw, 1.4rem)

}
```

```html
<div class="servicesOne">
    <img class="grid-item-four-one border-item-four-one" src=" https://www.viessmann.de/content/dam/vi-brands/DE/Services/services-xl.jpg/_jcr_content/renditions/services-s.jpg./services-s.jpg" alt="Our Services" srcset="">

    <h2 class="grid-item-four-two">Why <span style="color:#7EC8E3">JD3D</span>?</h2>

    <p class="grid-item-four-three"> Hendis et, omnimo et eum renduciati que nonse vollaccus verfernatur, odicit quatempossi ut int reratiam verorum.
        Hendis et, omnimo et eum renduciati que nonse vollaccus verfernatur, odicit quatempossi ut int reratiam verorum.
        Hendis et, omnimo et eum renduciati que nonse vollaccus verfernatur.
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use `minmax` property to define a range.

[As mdn says:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/minmax())

> The minmax() CSS function defines a size range greater than or equal
> to min and less than or equal to max. It is used with CSS Grids.

An example:

```css
.servicesOne {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(320px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.servicesOne .grid-item {
    border: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
    border-radius: .5rem;
}

img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="servicesOne">
        <div class="grid-item">
            <img class="grid-item"
            src=" https://www.viessmann.de/content/dam/vi-brands/DE/Services/services-xl.jpg/_jcr_content/renditions/services-s.jpg./services-s.jpg"
            alt="Our Services" srcset="">
        </div>
        <div  class="grid-item">
            <h2 class="grid-item" style="color:#7EC8E3">Why?</h2>
        </div>
        <div  class="grid-item">
            <p class="grid-item"> Hendis et, omnimo et eum renduciati que nonse vollaccus verfernatur, odicit quatempossi ut int reratiam verorum.
                Hendis et, omnimo et eum renduciati que nonse vollaccus verfernatur, odicit quatempossi ut int reratiam verorum.
                Hendis et, omnimo et eum renduciati que nonse vollaccus verfernatur.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```